# jQuery .off() not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm working with the DOM and I came along something strange. Here is the codes to add an event handler to an jQuery object:

```
 function randomizeTiles() {
       var $tiles = $("#letterbox a");
       $tiles.each(function() {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            var letter = frequencyTable[index];
            $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr("class") + " l" + letter);
            $(this).on("click.add", addLetter);
    });
    }
```

The code adds the event handler addLetter, which contains the code to remove the event handler once it's finished being called:

```
    function addLetter() {
  var tileClasses = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
  var letterClass = tileClasses[2];
  var tileLetter = letterClass.substring(1,2);

  var $currentWordDiv = $("#currentWord");
  if ($currentWordDiv.children().length === 0) {

  var $p = $("<p></p>");
  $currentWordDiv.append($p);
  $p.append(tileLetter);
  var $submitDiv = $("#submit");
  var a = $submitDiv.children(":first-child");


  a.on("click.sub", submitWord);
  }


  else {
    var p = $currentWordDiv.children(":first-child");
    //Get text value of the p element
    var letterText = p.text();
    //Adds the tile letter to current letter(s) in letterText
    letterText += tileLetter;
    //Replaces the current text with the updated text
    p.text(letterText);


  }

  $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr("class") + " disabled");
  $(this).off("click.add");


}
```

Although it works most of the time, there are times when the event handler still fires despite being removed. Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle so that further debugging can be accomplished?

Comment: I have created a fiddle based off of the information that you have provided so far. http://jsfiddle.net/XNu8K/

If you can add to this so that it's performing the functionality that you're having problems with, I can further debug any issues.

Comment: I have provided the HTML,CSS, and some more Javascript with it at http://jsfiddle.net/XNu8K/2/

Comment: Unfortunately, due to a dependency on outside resources I am not able to fully run and test what you have provided. However, after looking through your scripting I have made edits that I believe will help: http://jsfiddle.net/XNu8K/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use "one" instead of "on" if the event is only to be used once.

```
$(this).one("click.add", addLetter);
```

This will automatically unbind itself after firing the first time.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/one/

If randomizeTiles is called repeatedly you may be stacking bindings. If that is the case you may wish to change this to:

```
$(this).off("click.add").one("click.add", addLetter);
```

Comment: There's still an issue with the code. There's still that one tile that still fires despite it being "off."